# Run jquery on newly created elements

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery script which runs when the document is ready. It appends each of the existing elements "div.cool" with the text "[hi]" at the end.

Then I have an ajax script which loads new elements. When new elements are added with the class "div.cool", the jquery script doesnt append them.

What can I do to run the script when new elements are created?

**Example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/csDyM/3/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="cool">some text.</div>
    <div class="cool">some text.</div>
    <div class="cool">some text.</div>
    <div class="cool">some text.</div>
</div>

<a href="#_" onclick="loadmore();">ajax more</a>
```

**Javscript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.cool").append("[hi]");
});

function loadmore () {

    // this for loop represents the ajax dynamic content. it cannot be changed. 
    for (i=1;i<=4;i++) {
        $("div.container").append('<div class="cool">some text.</div>');
    } 

     // $("div.cool").append("[hi]"); adding this works but it appends existing elements
}
```

**The AJAX (replaced with for loop in exapmle):**

```
$.ajax({
    url: http://url.com/file.php,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
        $("div.container").html(html);
    }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't append `"[hi]"` because you're not appending `"[hi]"`.

Comment: Ugh, your update makes it entirely different. Do `var $html = $(html); $html.filter("div.cool").add($html.find("div.cool")).append("[hi]"); $html.appendTo("div.container");`

Comment: I had to change it or else the ajax part wouldnt work on jsfiddle.

Comment: The point is that your loop doesn't clearly demonstrate the HTML you're working with. If the response is actually `'<div class="cool">some text.</div>'`, then you'd still do the append directly. `$(html).append('[hi]').appendTo('div.container');`. If the elements are in larger bulk HTML, you'd do something closer to what I have in the comment above. Either way, you should do the modification before appending to the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a trigger class and test against it:

http://jsfiddle.net/euBYj/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.cool").append("[hi]").addClass("skip");
});


function loadmore () {

    for (i=1;i<=4;i++) {
        $("div.container").append('<div class="cool">some text.</div>');
    } 

    $("div.cool:not(.skip)").append("[hi]").addClass("skip");
}
```

Comment: This is neat, I like this solution better than mine :)

Comment: Why would you do it in two steps, and go to all the work of flagging the elements with a class? Seems over-engineered to me when you could just do `$('<div class="cool">some text.</div>').appendTo("div.container").append("[hi]");` http://jsfiddle.net/csDyM/8/

Comment: ^That for loop is just an example to represent the ajax content since I couldnt create an example with real ajax. It cant be changed.

Comment: I guess this is the best solution. THANK YOU

Comment: @supercoolville glad I could help, but would you consider taking a look at my comment on James' answer?

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
$('<div class="cool">some text.</div>')
    .append("[hi]")
    .appendTo("div.container");
```

Comment: Who on earth would down-vote this? It's by far the best solution.

Comment: you didnt read the example. I cant change contents inside the for loop.

Comment: @supercoolville: No, *you* didn't provide code that demonstrated what you were actually doing. James' answer is still the best way. It just needs to be modified a little for the *actual* situation.

Comment: In the interest of future visitors, this should not be down voted.  It provides the best solution for the given example.  If my solution helps the OP, that's well and good, but as for which one will provide most help to the most future visitors, that's an entirely different matter.  If it's not too much trouble to the OP, I think this should be marked as the answer... imo...

Answer (score 1):

Not very efficient, but it should work regardless:

```
function loadmore () {

    // grab existing elements from the DOM
    var $existing = $("div.cool");

    // this for loop represents the ajax dynamic content. it cannot be changed. 
    for (i=1;i<=4;i++) {
        $("div.container").append('<div class="cool">some text.</div>');
    } 

     $("div.cool").not($existing).append("[hi]"); 
}
```

Comment: This was the same approach I had thought of.  Seems like there should be a more efficient way of approaching this as jfriend00 suggests

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to append new elements received from an ajax call is to process the new elements right when they are first available in the success handler for the ajax call and only run the script on the new elements, not all the previous elements.

---

**Edit:**

Now, that you've shown us your ajax code, if what you're trying to do is to `append("[hi]")` on all new `div.cool` objects, then you can change your ajax code to this which will just process the new HTML as it arrives from the ajax call before it's inserted into your page.  Since it operates only on the newly arrived HTML, it won't modify anything else on the page.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://url.com/file.php",
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
        var newHTML = $(html);
        newHTML.find("div.cool").append("[hi]");
        $("div.container").empty().append(newHTML);
    }
});
```

Your ajax code looks a little odd to me because it's replacing all previous elements and I assumed you were adding new elements to what previously existed like your previous sample code.  Are you sure you posted the correct ajax code?

Comment: What can I run in the ajax success handler to only change new elements?

Comment: @supercoolville - Show us your ajax code with the format of the data it receives and we can advise.

Comment: @supercoolville: I think the point here also, was that new elements should be fully ready/polished once created, and should not need additional editing once appended.

Comment: @supercoolville - I added an example for how you can process the new HTML right in the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("div.cool").append("[hi]");
});

function loadmore () {
 var count = 0;
 $.each("div.container",function(){count++});
 // this for loop represents the ajax dynamic content. it cannot be changed. 
 for (i=1;i<=4;i++) {
     $("div.container").append('<div class="cool">some text.</div>');
 }
 var current = -1;
 $.each("div.container",function(){
  current++;
  if(current < count)continue;
  this.append("[hi]");
 });
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   addHi($("div.cool"));
});

function addHi(elem) {
   elem.append("[hi]");
}

function loadmore () {

    // this for loop represents the ajax dynamic content. it cannot be changed. 
    for (i=1;i<=4;i++) {
        var jqobj = $('<div class="cool">some text.</div>');
        addHi(jqobj);

        $("div.container").append(jqobj);
    } 

    // $("div.cool").append("[hi]"); adding this works but it appends existing elements
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Get the number of existing `div.cool`:

  `var original_number = $("div.cool").length;`
- Create new elements using ajax.
- Get new number of `div.cool`:

  `var new_number = $("div.cool").length;`
- Using a for loop append hi to new ones:

  ```
  for (i=original_number+1;i<=new_number;i++) {
      $("div.cool").eq(i).append('hi');
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen anyone use `.filter()` yet so I'll throw it out as a possibility. You can select all the elements and filter then down to only the ones you want:

```
$(".cool").filter(function () {

    //returns true if the end of the text string is not "[hi]" (which keeps it in the set of matched elements)
    return ($(this).text().slice(-4) != '[hi]')
}).append("[hi]");
```

The best solution is to alter the elements before adding them to the DOM like James Montagne did, I though I'd just demo this idea: http://jsfiddle.net/csDyM/9/